# Checkbox not pre populating on my form

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I have a form, and one question requires checkboxes. Someone fills out the form and they get an email where they approve or deny. If they deny, they get an email with a link that takes them back to the form (with a temp id). My form responses are saving for all my other elements but I can't get checkbox to store with what I entered. I would like it to show what checkboxes were checked when they filled out the form. What am missing to make that work?

```
 This is an update:

   <form name="iform" method="post" action="html_form.php" class="iform">
```

I have other questions too. Those all pre populate.

```
   <li>
   <label for="Ifyescheckone1">question:</label>
     <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="Ifyescheckone1[]" value="response 1" <?php if(isset($Ifyescheckone1) && in_array("reponse 1",$Ifyescheckone1)){print " checked=\"checked\"";} ?>> <label id="checkbox" for="Ifyescheckone1" class="ilabel">reponse 1</label></li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="Ifyescheckone1[]" value="reponse 2" <?php if(isset($Ifyescheckone1) && in_array("reponse 2",$Ifyescheckone1)){print " checked=\"checked\"";} ?>><label for="Ifyescheckone2" class="ilabel">reponse 2</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Ifyescheckone1[]" value="reponse 3" <?php if(isset($Ifyescheckone1) && in_array("reponse 3",$Ifyescheckone1)){print " checked=\"checked\"";} ?>><label for="Ifyescheckone3" class="ilabel">reponse 3</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="Ifyescheckone1[]" value="reponse 4" <?php if(isset($Ifyescheckone1) && in_array("reponse 4",$Ifyescheckone1)){print " checked=\"checked\"";} ?>><label for="Ifyescheckone4" class="ilabel">reponse 4</label></li>

   </ul></li>

      </form>
```

Comment: Can you show the html produced by this code?

Comment: I can't show the completed form.

Comment: Why would you not be able to show the form? How about outputting `var_dump($Ifyescheckone1)` above the code you pasted?

Comment: I updated my above question